# Is there any workaround for implicit user-defined conversion operator() to be considered when deducing function arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++20

Consider the following example, which tries to pass a `std::array` to a function. Naturally the "conversion" is not considered, but is there any work-around without having to be explicit? Especially if the class already provides the necessary properties (value_type etc.).

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Array_t
{
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = size_t;

    std::array<T, N> Internal{};

    constexpr operator auto() { return Internal; }
};

template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr bool Test(std::array<T, N> Input)
{
    return Input.size() == 32;
}

constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 32> OK1 = Array_t<uint8_t, 32>();
constexpr auto OK2 = Test((std::array<uint8_t, 32>)Array_t<uint8_t, 32>{});
constexpr auto OK3 = Test(Array_t<uint8_t, 32>().Internal);

// could not deduce template argument for 'std::array<_Ty,_Size>'
// from 'Array_t<uint8_t,32>'
constexpr auto FAIL = Test(Array_t<uint8_t, 32>{});
```

To clarify, a workaround so that the Array_t struct can be passed directly to any function expecting a std::array. No casting, no helper/conversion function, just some way to make the compiler understand that the struct is convertible. Possibly in a similar manner to CTAD.

Comment: "Especially if the base class" -- what base class?

Comment: No base class, unfortunate wording. Meant that both the user-defined class and the member contains the same template parameters, properties like value_type etc.

Comment: I suspect there's a duplicate of this somewhere, given how many times I've seen some form of this question here.  The short answer - I believe - is that C++ won't attempt every possible implicit conversion of a parameter to see if exactly one conversion would allow the template arguments to be deduced.  You _could_ [write a function overload](https://godbolt.org/z/E9W195TPW) that accepts `Array_t`.

Comment: @DrewDormann That's correct, hence why the question is about workarounds to make it work. For example, to fix the example code `Array_t` can inherit from `std:array` rather than having it as a member. But if there's some obscure way to tell the compiler to consider conversions in a more generic way (e.g. similar to CTAD), that'd be great.

Comment: why not just a static cast to express your intent?

Comment: Because I'd like to use the class with existing code, and having static_cast everywhere would get messy.

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question so it's clear whether you want CTAD or some other type of solution.  It's not clear to me how the link in my earlier comment does not qualify as a "workaround".  It may help everyone to clarify.

Comment: @DrewDormann As in, a way to be able to pass the struct directly, as one would with a normal `std::array`. Without explicit casting, conversion functions etc.. Something one can do to the struct itself, or a way to tell the compiler how to handle it.

Comment: You want problems? Then do implicit conversions. You will have problems, guaranteed. It's a no-brainer. Implicit conversion operator? -2, do not merge.

Comment: Yes, I love problems. Consider it an academic exercise if nothing else..

Comment: To answer the question in the title: no, absolutely not.

Comment: Overload the Test function for your type and forward the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template deduction never considers (user-defined) conversion. Given your:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr bool Test(std::array<T, N> Input);
```

If you see, in code, `Test(x)`, then that is only ever valid if `x` is either specifically some kind of `std::array` or inherits (publicly and unambiguously) from that.

If you want this to work, you have several different options of what to do (in my personal preference order):

1. You can make `Test` a broader function template, accepting anything that it could actually use instead of only specifically `std::array<T, N>`. Given that you said "Especially if the class already provides the necessary properties (value_type etc.)", this suggests that what you want for `Test` isn't specifically a `std::array`. So you should figure out what those actual properties are and write an appropriately-constrained function template. For instance, does any `ranges::contiguous_range` suffice or do you actually need compile-time size?  Do you even need contiguity? etc.
2. You can explicitly convert your `Array_t` to a `std::array` on the call-side. This works better if you give the conversion function a name, so you can write something like `obj.to_array()` rather than `static_cast<std::array<T, N>>(obj)` (which is both much longer to type and more annoying to get the parameters correct).
3. You can explicitly provide the necessary template arguments to `Test`, like `Test<uint8_t, 32>(obj)` - this avoids needing to deduce `T` and `N`, now you just have a normal function that takes a `std::array<uint8_t, 32>`, so conversions work just fine. Note that you have to provide *both*, `Test<uint8_t>(obj)` is insufficient.
4. You can make `Array_t<T, N>` inherit from `std::array<T, N>`, instead of just converting to it. That works right off the bat.

Comment: Thank you for the serious response. Point 4 is what I was planning to do if there wasn't a better answer on here, as I do indeed need the size at compiletime =)

Comment: Going to mark this as the solution. Had hoped for some new / obscure way to get it working, but this may be useful for others. Thank you again for the serious response =P